# Using SUM() in PIG Latin

Tags: loops, sum, apache-pig

I am just starting to write some scripts in PIG, and I am trying to SUM an int Column, My Script looks like this :

```
DATA = LOAD 'SomeFile' as (fingerPrint, size, str1, str2);
groupedChunks = GROUP DATA BY fingerPrint;


uniqueChunks = FILTER groupedChunks BY COUNT(DATA)==1;
sizes = FOREACH uniqueChunks GENERATE MAX($.size) as size;
```

Now I have a table, having just one column, which is the size column, if I would 
call DESCRIBE, it generates this Output: `sizes:{size: int}`

Now I need help in this step, how I do I get the SUM of all sizes of this column ?

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this?

```
result = FOREACH (GROUP sizes ALL) GENERATE SUM(sizes);
DUMP result;
```

**UPDATE: full code**

**input.txt**

```
a       1       b       c
d       2       e       f
```

**PigScript:**

```
DATA = LOAD 'input.txt' as (fingerPrint, size, str1, str2);
groupedChunks = GROUP DATA BY fingerPrint;
uniqueChunks = FILTER groupedChunks BY COUNT(DATA)==1;
sizes = FOREACH uniqueChunks GENERATE MAX(DATA.size) as size;
result = FOREACH (GROUP sizes ALL) GENERATE SUM(sizes);
DUMP result;
```

**Output:**

```
(3.0)
```

Comment: I am still getting the error, unable to open iterator for alias  result.
Does it has to do with Casting ? A warning by sizes: Encountered Warning IMPLICI_CAST_TO_LONG

Comment: a\t1\tb\tc
d\t2\te\tf

with \t I guess, you know I mean Tabular

Comment: Heyy thanks for that, do you think, it would be possible, that the problem is the line 
sizes = FOREACH uniqueChunks GENERATE MAX(DATA.size) as size;

would it make any difference to :

sizes = FOREACH uniqueChunks GENERATE MAX(DATA.size) as size;

However i just copied your script, and it still does not work, I get as an Output : read input successfully but pig failed to produce an output, making me wondering, if this is another issue in hadoop or pig ? because the jobs themselves are  always failing, but still I am getting the error : Unable to open Iterator fol alias result.

Answer (score 0):

V= GROUP DATA ALL;
result= FOREACH V GENERATE SUM(DATA.size)